# How can i wait for serial port to read?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

i have a device that receive data. i want to send this data to PC to show in data grid view . how can i wait for serial port to completely receive data ?. i have code dosen't work. ( "displayvalue" is a void convert byte to value )

```
 serialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
        byte[] byteToReceiv = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
        int count = serialPort.BytesToRead;
        var offset = 0;
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        while (count > 0) 
        {
            var readCount = serialPort.Read(byteToReceiv, offset, count);
            offset += readCount;
            count -= readCount;
            
        }
        textBox1.Text = displayValue(byteToReceiv);
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty to improve the tags, in particular to add the *c#* and *.net* tags as they are very relevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The SerialPort class has a DataReceived event which fires when data has been completely received. I would advise you to use it instead of using a timeout in this case.
You can find an example for the same in Microsoft's docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0